# make: Circular b <- b dependency dropped

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

For the example Makefile below, I was expecting and output of

Expected Output:

```
x/x_a
x/x_b
x/x_c
x/x_d
```

Code:

```
letters= a b c d 
default:$(letters)
$(letters):x/x_$(letters)
x/x_$(letters):
        echo $@
```

But what I got was

```
echo x/x_a
x/x_a
make: Circular b <- b dependency dropped.
make: Circular c <- b dependency dropped.
make: Circular c <- c dependency dropped.
make: Circular d <- b dependency dropped.
make: Circular d <- c dependency dropped.
make: Circular d <- d dependency dropped.
echo d
d
echo c
c
echo b
b
```

I am not sure what is causing

1. The circular dependency. It looks linear to me.
2. Printing of b,c,d instead of x/x_b,x/x_c,x/x_d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines don't do what you seem to think they do:

```
$(letters):x/x_$(letters)
x/x_$(letters):
```

Make variables are straight substitutions.  You are assuming that `x/x_$(letters)` will apply a prefix of `x/x_` to every word in `$(letters)`, but that's not true.  It's simple text substitution so the expansion of that is `x/x_a b c d`, so the above lines are:

```
a b c d:x/x_a b c d
x/x_a b c d:
```

which explains the behavior you see.  If you want to apply the prefix to each word you need a function (since you're using GNU make):

```
letters := a b c d
xletters := $(addprefix x/x_,$(letters))

$(letters): $(xletters)
$(xletters):
```